# Magento - Get products price with tax and discounts in cart/order (Criteo tags)

Tags: magento, cart, criteo

For the implementation of Criteo tags, I'm trying to get the price (among other things) of all products in the cart (and success page) with tax and discounts. 
I'm currently doing something like this, but it only displays price with discount and without tax :

```
$cartAllItems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems();
foreach ($cartAllItems as $item){
    $price = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($item->getProduct(), $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice());
    // other things
}
```

I've been testing around a lot of things and can't make it work.
Thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use,

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount')
```

This will return you total tax amount.
or you can use

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); 
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue()); 
$grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); 
if(isset($totals['discount']) &#038;&#038; $totals['discount']->getValue()) {
   $discount = round($totals['discount']->getValue()); 
} else {
   $discount = '';
}
if(isset($totals['tax']) &#038;&#038; $totals['tax']->getValue()) {
  $tax = round($totals['tax']->getValue()); 
} else {
  $tax = '';
}
```

**Modified**
I guess for your requirement

```
foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
  $_product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);   
  $productsPrice = floatval($_product->getData("price")); 

  // Get the product's tax class' ID
  $taxClassId = $_product->getData("tax_class_id");
  echo 'Tax Class ID '.$taxClassId.'
';
  // Get the tax rates of each tax class in an associative array
  $taxClasses  = Mage::helper("core")->jsonDecode( Mage::helper("tax")-        
>getAllRatesByProductClass() );
  echo 'Tax Classes '.$taxClasses.'
';
  // Extract the tax rate from the array
  $taxRate   = $taxClasses["value_".$taxClassId];
  echo 'Tax Rate '.$taxRate.'
';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. The thing is, I'm looking to get the price (discounted and with taxes in it) for EACH item of my cart (hence my foreach). Is there a way to do that with your method ? Thanks.

Comment: try, <?php
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore('default');
    $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest(null, null, null, $store);
    $taxclassid = $item->getData('tax_class_id')
    $percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($request->setProductClassId($taxclassid));
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can get the discount and tax value per item and make the calculation.

```
$_item->getDiscountAmount
$_item->getTaxAmount

$totalItemPrice = $_item->getPrice - $_item->getDiscountAmount + $_item->getTaxAmount
```